# Feed_dict doesnt accept my data

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, tensorflow

I've been trying to be able to feed my own images in some tensorflow code to look how the code would react to my own images instead of the MNIST set. I've been able to import images(i think) into tensorflow but I have two placeholders that should get my image data and label data. I tried to use feed_dict(which still seems right to me) to be able to use my data in the rest of my code but it won't accept any data I feed it. I know I can't feed it a Tensor and apparently not a batch but the only way I can think of to make this work is to feed it a list. I saw feed_dict is able to use numpy arrays but im not sure how i should approach converting data to a numpy array.

I'm new to TensorFlow and python so please forgive any mistakes I made, I'm still learning how everything works.

```
with tf.name_scope('Image_Data_Input'):
  def read_labeled_image_list(image_list_file):
    print('read_labeled_image_list function opened')
    f = open(image_list_file, 'r') 
    print('image_list_file opened')
    filenames = []
    labels = []
    print('Arrays formed')
    for line in f:
      filename, label = line[:-1].split(' ')
      filenames.append(filename)
      labels.append(label)
    print('Lines deconstructed')
    return filenames, labels

def read_image(input_queue):
    label = input_queue[1]
    file_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
    decoded_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_contents, channels=3)
    print('Image decoded to JPEG')
    decoded_image.set_shape([2560, 1440, 3])
    decoded_image = tf.image.resize_images(decoded_image, [128, 128])
    return decoded_image, label

image_list, label_list = read_labeled_image_list(image_list_file)
images = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_list, dtype=tf.string)
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_list, dtype=tf.string)

input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels], num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)

image, label = read_image(input_queue)
```

The indentation behaved a little weird when i pasted my code so I'm not sure everything is properly placed.

Well now I have these placeholder:

```
with tf.name_scope('input'):
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
```

And I've seen the code routing data to those placeholder this way:

```
batch_x, batch_y = tf.train.batch([image, label], batchsize)
#_, summary = sess.run([train_writer, summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y})
```

But I can't seem to make this work.

Does anyone have any idea how i could make this work?

Again sorry for any mistakes and thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the error that you're getting?

Comment: TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. acceptable feed values include python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarray or tensorhandles

Comment: where do you define `IMAGES` and `LABELS`?

Comment: Sorry, those originally were batch_x and batch_y, i changed the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you can't feed tensors into a placeholder. `batch_x` and `batch_y` are tensors. The new `tf.Dataset` API is the preferred way to input data into a model (guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)). I think `Dataset.from_tensor_slices` would require minimal rewriting. Short of that, build the graph so that `batch_x` and `batch_y` flow into the model you're using directly. Then you don't need to use placeholders.

I don't recommend this, but for completeness I want to mention another method. You could:

```
numpy_batch_x, numpy_batch_y = sess.run([batch_x, batch_y])
_, summary = sess.run([train_writer, summary_op], 
    feed_dict={x: numpy_batch_x, y_: numpy_batch_y})
```

PS: If `train_writer` is a `tf.summary.FileWriter`, I think you want to:

```
summary = sess.run([summary_op], ...)
train_writer.add_summary(summary)
```

**EDIT**: In response to confusion on the dataset API, I am going to show how to handle this with a Dataset. I am going to use TFRecords. It may not be the simplest solution, but it's one way.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread  # There are others that would work here.
from cv2 import resize  # Again, others to choose from.

def read_labeled_image_list(...)
    # See question
    return filenames, labels

def make_tfr(tfr_dir="/YOUR/PREFERRED/TFR/DIR")
    def _int64_list_feature(a_list):
        return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=a_list)

    def _bytes_feature(value):
        return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfr_dir)
    all_image_paths, all_labels = read_labeled_image_list(...)
    for path, label in zip(all_image_paths, all_labels):
        disk_im = imread(path)
        resized_im = cv2.resize(disk_im, (128, 128))
        raw_im = resized_im.tostring()
        # Construct an example proto-obj,
        example = tf.train.Example(
            # which wants a Features proto-obj,
            features=tf.train.Features(
                # which wants a dict.
                feature={
                    'image_raw': _bytes_feature(raw_im),
                    'label': _int64_list_feature(label)
        })) # close your example object
        serialized = example.SerializeToString()
        writer.write(serialized)

make_tfr()  # After you've done it successfully once, comment out.

def input_pipeline(batch_size, epochs, tfr_dir="/YOUR/PREFERRED/TFR/DIR"):
    # with tf.name_scope("Input"):  maybe you like to scope as much as I do?
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfr_dir)

    def parse_protocol_buffer(example_proto):
        features = {'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
                    'label': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64)}
        parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(
            example_proto, features)
        return parsed_features['image_raw'], parsed_features['label']

    dataset = dataset.map(parse_protocol_buffer)

    def convert_parsed_proto_to_input(image_string, label):
        image_decoded = tf.decode_raw(image_string, tf.uint8)
        image_resized = tf.reshape(image_decoded, (128, 128, 3))
        image = tf.cast(image_resized, tf.float32)
        # I usually put my image elements in [-1, 1]
        return image * (2. /255) -1, label

    dataset = dataset.map(converted_parsed_proto_to_input)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(batch_size * epochs)
    return dataset

def model(image_tensor):
    ...
    # However you want to do this.
    return predictions

def loss(predictions, labels):
    ...
    return some_loss

def train(some_loss):
    ...
    return train_op

batch_size = 50
iterations = 10000
train_dataset = input_pipeline(batch_size, iterations)
train_iterator = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
image, label = train_iterator.get_next()
predictions = model(image)
loss_op = loss(image, predictions)
train_op = train(loss_op)
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/YOUR/LOGDIR", sess.graph)
    sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
    for epoch in range(iterations + 1):
        _, summary = sess.run([train_op, summary_op])
        train_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)
```

You say you're new to TensorFlow. I hope this doesn't intimidate you. I was new to TensorFlow not long ago, and it was a pain to figure out how to make a good input pipeline. Learning TFRecords seemed impossible. You also say you're new to Python, so I'll warn you that `cv2` has a reputation of difficult installs. You may want to look into other ways to resize an image (though I'd advise against PIL, which is probably even more confusing and difficult at first).

Basically, I'm posting this code because because the documentation on writing TFRecords is confusing ([Exhibit A](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/reading_data/) vs a [blog post](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/) that helped me figure it out) but TFRecords is the way I know how to make a Dataset best. Even if you don't go the TFRecords route, this could help you with the `map` function for datasets, e.g. notice how I pass `label` through `convert...` even though it's not used. Making a dataset (specifically from TFRecords) is a lot of lines of code, but `Dataset` is the preferred way to construct an input pipeline and it's designed to replace the old `queue` method you're using.

As a side note, the purpose of the `queue` strategy was to read data from memory directly into the graph *without* placeholders. Placeholders are slow and memory-intensive compared to the queue strategy, but Datasets are even better when implemented correctly.

I see in your comment that you want to see the placeholder namescope get connected to your graph. The dataset way, you'll see some dataset nodes on the graph. If you scope them with what I commented out, it should be apparent that everything's hooked up right. Your way, you're actually adding this queue-and-preprocess structure onto the graph. Since you'll have to de-tensor-ify the images to pass them into a placeholder, it won't be apparent that your data is flowing correctly.

Now, as I mentioned in the original post, you can just pass `batch_x` and `batch_y` into your model and forget the `placeholder` and dataset altogether. You'll see everything hooked up right from the preprocessing stage, if the queue is implemented right. Still, your images are large before reshaping them. Reading them will be an intensive task. I'd recommend going the hard route of learning to use `Datasets` and `TFRecords`.

I hope this helps you implement a Dataset in your code. I hope this helps you get TensorBoard running. And I hope this helps you figure out TFRecords if you decide to go that route.

PS: On the topic of TensorBoard validating that the model is working, you could attach a `tf.summary.image(img)` as the first line of `model(...)`. Then check out the image dash and see if it's what you expect.

**EDIT 2**: `example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={}))`

Comment: I'll look into the dataset guide you linked, thanks in advance. I've been using placeholders so i can watch if my the whole placeholder namescope gets connected to the rest of my graph so I can immediately see if everything works but ultimately that would work better indeed. I didn't look at the add_summary so far because of my current problem(and because of the fact a graph is all the visualisation i need to check if my input works correctly) but thanks anyway :)

Comment: The main problem I run into with the Dataset.from_tensor_slices is the use of a numpy array. I don't have my data in a .npy file format and I can't find how to make a file like that anywhere(I feel like this happens 50% of the time in Tensorflow documentation). That'd mean I'd have to transform my data into a numpy array somehow but I have no idea how to approach that since the documentation for numpy arrays doesn't really take things like this into account. In short: I'm totally lost on how to implement Dataset.from_tensor_slices in my code.

Comment: @WilrickB Check out the edit. Good point about `.npy`, I didn't think about that. (In my opinion, you're right about the TensorFlow docs, too!)

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you so much! Even tough this might take me a while to understand fully it looks more comprehensive than other sources I've been able to find. I've looked at PIL and pillow and I'm not a huge fan either so I'll probably give cv2 a go. Can't learn anything if I don't try it right? Anyway I can really work with this thanks again and I'll definitely follow up with how I made things work. Oh and I do indeed like to scope.

Comment: I've been busy with the code and I'm running into one problem. In the code there's this piece: _raw im = resized im.tostring()_. When resized im gets transformed to a string and it's passed to _return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))_ I get this error: _'p' has type <class 'str'>, but expected one of: (<class 'int'>,)_. I'm not sure what those parenthesises are doing around the int class. I'm thinking my input file might be different than yours which causes the code to print an error or might there be another explanation?

Comment: I *believe* the issue is that I missed a layer of the `example = tf.train.Example(...)` onion. The edit will hopefully fix the problem. If not, let me know and I'll take another look.

Comment: Absolutely right! Immediately explains the parenthesises around the <class 'int'> error. You are my hero man you're really helping me out here

Comment: Hi Dylan F,

I've been looking over the code and I'm sorry to say that I can't get it working properly. This definitely isn't a problem on your side I now understand how to make TFRecords which works better in a smaller, les complicated test i made. I'm having difficulty passing the data trough the 3 'def' parts because simply said, I don't understand Tensorflow well enough yet. If you would like to help me understand I would really appreciate it but I'd like to thank you for your help with the input pipeline already anyway.

Comment: @WilrickB We're moving outside of the scope of this SO question. I'm happy to help, but let's move to [this](https://github.com/flauted/tf-tut/blob/master/celeba_tutorial.ipynb) Jupyter Notebook on my Github. Feel free to start an Issue where we can discuss any questions you have.